# Cannot deactivate airplane mode

Tags: networking, wireless, airplane-mode

I have an infoway laptop WP1710. It had Windows installed on it. I installed Debian on it and the wifi was working. After this, I installed Ubuntu 17.10. Wifi is not working in Ubuntu but is working fine in Debian.

System is having the 'Airplane mode' activated and it is not possible for me to deactivate it on the laptop.

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company U98Z062.12 802.11bgn Wireless Half-size Mini PCIe Card [103c:3040]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k

$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Comment: I assume *flymodos* means 'Airplane Mode.' Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Is the module *hp-wmi* loaded? Check and post: `lsmod | grep wmi`